# Use local nginx proxy with dockerized images

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I just installed nginx server in ubuntu 22.04

I created a new config file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/bimawelcome.

here the nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/bimawelcome command

```
upstream react-client {
    server server-ip-address:3000;
}

upstream node-server {
    server server-ip-address:8000;
}
upstream json-server {
    server server-ip-address:80;
}
upstream fastapi-server {
    server server-ip-address:5000;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name bimawelcome.com;


location  / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    rewrite ^/$ http://localhost/bimawelcome/ redirect;
 }

location  /bimawelcome/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    rewrite /bimawelcome/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://react-client;
}

location /node-server {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    rewrite /node-server/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://node-server;
}

location /fastapi-server {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    rewrite /fastapi-server/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://fastapi-server;
}

 location /json-server {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    rewrite /json-server/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://json-server;
}
```

then I added it via this command

`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/bimawelcome /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

I test my code wiht sudo nginx -t

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and then restart my nginx

for the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    json-server:
        image: myusername/fake-server
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 4000:80
    react:
        image: myusername/bimawelcome-front-end
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 3000:3000
        depends_on :
          - node-server
          - fastapi-server
          - json-server
    node-server:
        image: myusername/bimawelcome-node-backend
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
    fastapi-server:
        image: myusername/fastapi-image
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
```

then I run `docker-compose up -d`

So in my server when i Hit 3000 port I acces to my fornt-end up

but when I try to use myserverip/bimawelcome I have always 404

What I'm missing ?

before I put my nginx server in the docker compose and evrything is ok, but now I decied to install nginx on my local machine and user docker for other app this dit not work

I like to acces my app via myserverip/bimawelcome and of course bimawelcome app can acces to backend server without CORS origin problem

Thank you